# offset with parameter in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have a PL/SQL procedure.  It executes a SQL statement and returns a json responce.

I would like to limit the rows returned using the offset clause.  eg:

```
select *    
from wherever
where something = parameter
offset 0 rows 
fetch next 25 rows only;
```

However I don't seem able to use variables to replace the 0 and the 25 in the example above.

Of course there are ways to work around this.  I can write code like we had to before the offset clause appeared in 11g.  But it looks ugly and possibly won't perform as well....am I missing something.  Can a parameter be used in the offset clause of SQL in a proc or cursor?

For example the following proc does compile but the cursor returned is always empty (its not when I hard code in values):

```
procedure test (pPageSize in pls_integer:=25, pPageno in pls_integer:=1, RecipeList out sys_refcursor) is
      vNextRows pls_integer;
      vOffset pls_integer; 
    begin
        vOffset:= pPageSize*(pPageno-1);
        vNextRows:= pPageSize;          

        open RecipeList 
            for
            select *      
            from recipes       
            order by recipeno
            offset vOffset rows 
            fetch next vNextRows rows only; 
       
end test;
```

Comment: Parameters can be used in an offset clause in a procedure or cursor. Also offset and fetch were introduced in 12c.

Comment: [Seems to work OK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=293538795e6bec9254f5a537e0964fd7). Maybe show a complete code example that doesn't, and the error you get?

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
declare
  start_row integer := 0;
  fetch_rows integer := 5;
begin
  
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'First ' || fetch_rows );
  for t in ( 
    select * from all_tables 
    offset start_row rows 
    fetch first fetch_rows rows only 
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line ( t.table_name );
  end loop;
  
  start_row := 5;
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Next ' || fetch_rows );
  for t in ( 
    select * from all_tables 
    offset start_row rows 
    fetch first fetch_rows rows only 
  ) loop
    dbms_output.put_line ( t.table_name );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call the procedure as

```
test (null, null, :bind_rc)
```

you are overriding the default values; if you want to use the defaults then don't supply the first two arguments:

```
test (RecipeList => :bind_rc)
```

or if you don't want to use the defaults then do supply arguments:

```
test (10, 11, :bind_rc)
test (pPageSize >= 10, pPageno => 2, RecipeList => :bind_rc)
```

or to leave the size as the default but get a specific page:

```
test (pPageno => 3, RecipeList => :bind_rc)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=094eb3be9dabb07529d0f35e7acb7b0a)

---

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/formal-parameter-declaration.html):

> Default value of the formal parameter that you are declaring. The data type of expression must be compatible with datatype.
>
> If a subprogram invocation does not specify an actual parameter for the formal parameter, then that invocation evaluates expression and assigns its value to the formal parameter.
>
> If a subprogram invocation does specify an actual parameter for the formal parameter, then that invocation assigns the value of the actual parameter to the formal parameter and does not evaluate expression.

You *are* specifying the actual parameters. You are passing null, but that means you are specifying the formal parameters as null - and *not* that you are not specifying them at all. A subtle but important difference.

---

> I guess I coudl set up default manually in the proc if I were keen.

Yes, fairly simply:

```
vOffset:= nvl(pPageSize, 25) * (nvl(pPageno, 1) -1);
vNextRows:= nvl(pPageSize, 25);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=101c8d854970964a700040488ed0a584)

Comment: Thanks.  I was testing through ORDS and an auto rest enabled proc using POST and I found that all the default parameters are replaced which I was not expecting.  I only realised when I tried managing pagination another way and the problem persisted.  It still seems very strange to me that I have to explicitly send every parameter.  I guess I coudl set up default manually in the proc if I were keen.  At least its working.  Thanks for spending time looking at this for me.

Comment: Yes, that would be fairly trivial, with `nvl()`; added to the answer for fun. No idea about ORDS *8-)

Comment: haha yes I added an if statement - which is consistent with how I prepare other variables - but yes nvl would work well too.  
Its possibly obvious but I'm very much just starting to learn about ORDS...It looks like ORDS could be useful if I get the hang of it.  I suppose an empty post content could be taken to imply NULL vales and so the behavior is reasonable.   Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it.

It is working fine if you pass the value to the procedure. it is not working with the default value.

-- Creating the procedure

```
SQL> CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE TEST1 (
  2  PPAGESIZE    IN    PLS_INTEGER:= 5, -- or default 5
  3  PPAGENO      IN    PLS_INTEGER:= 1, -- or default 1
  4  RECIPELIST   OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
  5  ) IS
  6  VNEXTROWS   PLS_INTEGER;
  7  VOFFSET     PLS_INTEGER;
  8  BEGIN
  9  VOFFSET     := PPAGESIZE * ( PPAGENO - 1 );
 10  VNEXTROWS   := PPAGESIZE;
 11  OPEN RECIPELIST FOR SELECT *
 12                        FROM T
 13                       ORDER BY A OFFSET VOFFSET ROWS
 14   FETCH NEXT
 15  VNEXTROWS ROWS ONLY;
 16  END TEST1;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

-- not working with the default value

```
SQL> var res refcursor;
SQL> exec TEST1(null,null,:res);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :res;

no rows selected
```

-- working with the non-default value

```
SQL> exec TEST1(5,1,:res);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :res;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          2
         3                     2
         4          3          4
         8          9          6
        12         12         12

SQL>
```

Comment: You're overriding the defaults when you call it as `TEST1(null,null,:res)`. If you call it with `TEST1(recipelist=>:res)` instead then those defaults are applied.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but this is what I wanted to convey.